# LikeView Callback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-likebox

I am integrating Facebook LikeView in a fragment of Android App as defined in official [fb docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button).

```
LikeView like_button = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
like_button.setObjectId(...);
```

I've also handled onActivityResult like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, null);
.....
}
```

I am unable to programmatically find if user have liked the page or unliked it from the LikeView. onActivityResults fires everytime the likeview's pop up returns but with no information  about the result.

Please help me in identifying what am i missing.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is intentional. Why do you want to know if the user has liked the page or not?

Comment: We want to award the customer if he/she have liked the page. I've called the Graph API "/me/likes/{pageid}" in OnActivityResult event to know if user've liked the page, but seems like this event is not a correct place. Even if user've liked the page, the graph api sometime returns empty dataset.

Comment: There is one another downside of using the Graph API "/me/likes/pageid" that we need "user_likes" permission also for this api to work.

Comment: Like I said, this is intentional because you need the additional permission. You also can't incentivize a user to like your page, which is why I'm asking why you need this information.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but there are lot of apps/games already offering something if user like/share their page, are they not following up the guidelines?

Comment: There are correct and incorrect ways of incentivizing users. See section 4.5 of the Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 7):

You can get the user's actions by adding this code to your `onActivityResults`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       default:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // verify we're returning from like action
                if ("com.facebook.platform.action.request.LIKE_DIALOG".equals(data.getStringExtra("com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION"))) {
                    // get action results
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras().getBundle("com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS");
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        bundle.getBoolean("object_is_liked"); // liked/unliked
                        bundle.getInt("didComplete");
                        bundle.getInt("like_count"); // object like count
                        bundle.getString("like_count_string");
                        bundle.getString("social_sentence");
                        bundle.getString("completionGesture"); // liked/cancel/unliked
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
}
```

Comment: data might not have the extra "com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION", but still contain everything @Duda said in the "com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS" bundle.

I simpy check if data.hasExtra("com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS")

Comment: Check `data != null` before using it can avoid some crashes.

Comment: there is no need to hardcode "com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS". It is a public static constant "NativeProtocol.EXTRA_PROTOCOL_METHOD_RESULTS"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```
        private String siLeGusta = "";    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
            ...
            ...

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); // si estas en un activity diferente

            String solicitud = "/"+uid+"/likes/"+page_id; //uid=user_id, page_id = el id de la pagina que deseas saber si ya tiene like del usuario.
            new Request(
                    session,
                    solicitud, //"/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                            //String s = txtFinal.getText().toString();
                            if (graphObject != null) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                                try {
                                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                                        siLeGusta = object.get("id").toString();

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            if (siLeGusta.equals(page_id)){
                                likeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                txtFinal.setText("A tí te gusta la página de ....");
                                txtFinal.setTextSize(30);

                            }else{
                                txtFinal.setText("Todavía no has dado LIKE a la página de ....");
                                txtFinal.setTextSize(30);
                                likeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

... //otras instrucciones aquí.

    }
```

Comment: Please explain how that answers the poster's question, especially as the Spanish comments and variable names makes it difficult to understand the code alone.

Comment: This answer helped me. Specially the idea is ok. But the from SDK v4, it seems we can'

Comment: never saw variables in mother tongue, they should make SDK's language compliant...